# Maintain JavaScript-appended items after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want my appended `<tr>` elements to remain the same after refreshing the page.

For example, when I register a user, the data is appended to a table row. I want to add new users, but I want the ones I added before to remain in the table, too.

```
$("#tesdiq").click(function () 
    $(".regForm").hide();
    $(".myTable").show();

    var ad = $("#ad").val();
    var soyad = $("#soyad").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var sheher = $("#sheher").val();

    var infolar = ("<tr><td>" + ad + "</td>" + "<td>" + soyad + "</td>" + "<td>" + email + "</td>" + "<td>" + sheher + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='sil'></td></tr>");

    $(".myTable table tbody").append(infolar);


localStorage.setItem("ad", ad);
localStorage.setItem("soyad",soyad);
localStorage.setItem("email",email);
localStorage.setItem("sheher",sheher);
```

I tried this, but it works just one time:

```js
var myUser = localStorage.getItem("ad");

if (myUser) {

  var yeni = ("<tr><td>" + localStorage.getItem("ad") + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("soyad") + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("email") + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("sheher") +
    "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='sil'></td></tr>");
    
  $(".myTable table tbody").append(yeni);
  
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're part way there. Pull the data out of local storage and populate the table. What seems to be going wrong?

Comment: I do not know how to do it(

Comment: I tried get item but it seems to be not working

Comment: It might help to show what you tried and what specifically goes wrong. It's useful to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i tried that but it works just one time 

var myUser = localStorage.getItem("ad");

if(myUser){


    var yeni = ("<tr><td>" + localStorage.getItem("ad") + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("soyad") + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("email") + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.getItem("sheher") + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='sil'></td></tr>");
    
    $(".myTable table tbody").append(yeni);

}

Comment: Let me explain. it's a registration form and there will be users. For example i have one user registered it will be appended to a row with its name and info. i want a new user to ad but remain the one i added before  in the table too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tesdiq").click(function () 
    $(".regForm").hide();
    $(".myTable").show();

    var ad = localStorage.getItem("ad") || $("#ad").val();
    var soyad = localStorage.getItem("soyad") || $("#soyad").val();
    var email = localStorage.getItem("email") || $("#email").val();
    var sheher = localStorage.getItem("sheher") ||  $("#sheher").val();

    var infolar = ("<tr><td>" + ad + "</td>" + "<td>" + soyad + "</td>" + "<td>" + email + "</td>" + "<td>" + sheher + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' name='sil'></td></tr>");

    $(".myTable table tbody").append(infolar);


localStorage.setItem("ad", ad);
localStorage.setItem("soyad",soyad);
localStorage.setItem("email",email);
localStorage.setItem("sheher",sheher);
```

Comment: Click evet is for adding a new row to my table. It's like a registration form. when i click the button it adds a new user and i want it to remain the same after refreshing

Answer (score 0):

you cant remain the same in the page after refresh, bcs it working on a click event

```
$("#tesdiq").click(function () {}
```

You should write this on onload event, then it will be there after refresh

Comment: Click event is for adding a new row to my table. It's like a registration form. when i click the button it adds a new user and i want it to remain the same after refreshing

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to save form data as objects in an array.

You can serialize form data, make an object, and push it onto an array. Then use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the resulting array of objects into a JSON string and store it in local storage. When you retrieve the data from local storage, you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the JSON back into an array of objects. You can then add the data from those objects to the HTML table.

It looks like you're using jQuery, so I've used it in my example:

```js
//localStorage.clear();

let $form = $('#regForm');
let $table = $('#userTable');

// get and parse local storage JSON
let regData = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('regData')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('regData'))
  : [];

// function to add row to table
function addTableRow(row) {
  let $thisRow = $('<tr>');
  $.each(row, function() {
    $('<td>', {
      'text': this
    }).appendTo($thisRow);
  });
  $thisRow.appendTo($table);
}

// add rows from local storage to table
$.each(regData, function() {
  addTableRow(this);
});

// add row from form to local storage and table
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
  let formData = {};
  $.each($form.serializeArray(), function() {
    formData[this.name] = this.value;
  });
  regData.push(formData);
  localStorage.setItem('regData', JSON.stringify(regData));
  addTableRow(formData);
  $form[0].reset();
});
```

```css
#userTable {
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

form label,
form label span {
  display: block;
}

#addRow {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form id="regForm">
  <label>
    <span>First Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Last Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Email</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Phone Number</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
  </label>
  <button type="button" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
</form>
```

[View Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s0jq3wo/)

Also see [Using HTML5 Local Storage as a Client-Side Database](https://selftaughtcoders.com/local-storage-client-side-database/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

However, i did not get this part let regData = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('regData')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('regData'))
  : [];

What does this mean . Why we do not created an array but did it this way?

Comment: That's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It means: If there's a regData property in localStorage, store it in the regData variable; otherwise, set the regData variable to an empty array. It's equivalent to this: `if (local storage exists) { set variable to local storage } else { set variable to empty array }`